# Export sorted View to JSON

Tags: 7, views

I need some expert help. I need to export data into JSON. Here are the steps I followed:

1> Created a draggable view to allow admin to provide appropriate sort order.
ref (https://3cwebservices.com/drupal/creating-drag-drop-sorting-interface-drupal-view)

2> Adding a page on the same view, with format as 'JSON data document'

I can see the output in JSON format but the SORT order provided by admin is missing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used the query generated by the drupal page and generated JSON programmatically.